# Processing - Found one too many { characters without a } character afterward

Tags: java, switch-statement, case, processing, curly-braces

Here is my code... can someone please tell me what is wrong?

```
void keyPressed() {

    if (key == '\n') {
       equation = typing;
       switch (equation.charAt(2)) {

            case "-":
                if (equation.charAt(3) == "x") {
                    math[0] = -1;
                };
                else {
                     math[0] = int(equation.charAt(3) * -1);
                };
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand what is wrong. All of the braces match up. Is it that you can't use an if else inside a switch???

Comment: looks like you have an extra `;` before the `else` statement. Try deleting it.

Answer (score 3):

try replacing

```
if (equation.charAt(3)=="x") {
    math[0] = -1;
  };
  else {
    math[0] = int(equation.charAt(3)*-1);
  };
```

with

```
if (equation.charAt(3)=='x') {  // NOTE character comparision
    math[0] = -1;
  }
  else {
    math[0] = int(equation.charAt(3)*-1);
  }
```

Comment: and equation.charAt(3)=="x" should be equation.charAt(3)=='x'

Comment: Also, you should compare a `char` to a `char` with single quotes. `if(equation.charAt(3) == 'x') { /* stuff */ }`